# MySQL WHERE NOT IN extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Below is a SQL statement inside a stored procedure (*truncated for brevity*):

```
SELECT * 
FROM item a 
WHERE a.orderId NOT IN (SELECT orderId FROM table_excluded_item);
```

This statement takes 30 seconds or so! But if I remove the inner SELECT query, it drops to 1s. `table_excluded_item` is not huge, but I suspect the inner query is being executed more than it needs to be.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The inner query is a dependent subquery, which are notorious bottlenecks because the subquery is run against each row of the outer query. Check out [Optimizing Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html) on the MySQL dev site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.* 
FROM    item a 
        LEFT JOIN table_excluded_item b
            ON a.orderId = b.orderId
WHERE   b.orderId IS NULL
```

make sure that `orderId` from both tables has been indexed.

Comment: Hey, that works, thanks! Now it's down to 2s. The language always seems very counter-intuitive to me :(

Comment: A clever solution, although I didn't see the performance improvement. But things have changed in the last 9 years.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the left join approach is that duplicate records might be processed in generating the output. Sometimes, this is not the case . . . according to this [article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), MySQL does optimize the `left outer join` correctly when the columns are indexed, even in the presence of duplicates.  I admit to remaining skeptical, though, that this optimization always happens.

MySQL sometimes has problems optimizing `IN` statements with a subquery.  The best fix is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item a 
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from table_excluded_item tei
                  where tei.orderid = a.orderid
                  limit 1
                 )
```

If you have an index on table_excluded_item.orderid, then this will scan the index and stop at the first value (the `limit 1` may not be strictly necessary for this).  This is the fastest and safest way to implement what you want in MySQL.

Comment: Technically the `limit 1` is not necessary; the "anti-join" will do exactly the same thing anyway. (It *could be* that mysql is not smart enough to know this)

Comment: "The problem with the left join approach is that you can get duplicate records in the output." -- why? remember that you are searching for non-existent record.

Comment: @jW . . . I rephrased this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and compare to the `LEFT JOIN` query time:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item a 
HAVING orderId NOT IN (SELECT orderId FROM table_excluded_item);
```

This is frowned upon (using `HAVING` when `WHERE` can be used) since `HAVING` assumes that the limiting condition (`orderId`) is part of the result set. But I think in this scenarios it makes more sense (since it is part of the result set) and because it is clearer what is going on than the `LEFT JOIN` approach.

It may actually be a bit slower, but post the results so we know if it's any better than your original query.

Comment: cheers - on my dataset I consistently got ~7s for this vs ~8s for the left join approach